# Call to undefined function cell()

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, call

I am trying to build a simple pagination in PHP. But for some reason it keeps outputting the error. I just can't seem to find the issue. Here is my code:

PHP :

```
include_once('connect.php'); // connect to db is successful
$count_query = mysql_query("SELECT NULL FROM users");
$count = mysql_num_rows($count_query);

// pagination starts here
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = preg_replace("#[^0-9]#", "", $_GET['page']);
} else {
    $page = 1;
}

$perPage = 5;
$lastPage = cell($count / $perPage);

if ($page < 1) {
    $page = 1;
} else if ($page > $lastPage) {
    $page = $lastPage;
}

$limit = "LIMIT " . ($page - 1) * $perPage . ", $perPage";
$query = mysql_query('SELECT first_name FROM users ORDER BY user_id DESC $limit');

if ($lastPage != 1) {
    if ($page != $lastPage) {
        $next = $page + 1;
        $pagination .= '<a href="index.php?page=' . $next . '">Next</a>';
    }

    if ($page != $lastPage) {
        $prev = $page - 1;
        $pagination .= '<a href="index.php?page=' . $prev . '">Previous</a>';
    }
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $output .= $row['first_name'] . '<hr />';
}
```

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pagination</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Pagination</a>
        <?php echo $output; ?>
        <?php echo $pagination; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

As said in the title, i'm getting a `"Fatal error: Call to undefined function cell()"`.
I've spent hours of fixing and still no luck. I hope you guys figure it out and let me know what's the problem.

Comment: So where are you defining the function called cell()... or do you mean [ceil()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php)?

Comment: Yeah my mistake, I meant to write ceil there. I can't believe that slipped through! Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is telling you that you are calling an undefined function. Your problem looks to be over here.

```
$lastPage = cell($count / $perPage);
```

You mean [`ceil()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php), not `cell()`.

Simple spelling mistake, it is short for ceiling.

Answer (score 0):

cell is a function call that PHP can't find...

You haven't shown it in your code so does it exist?